# Запятая перед поэтому

Tags: пунктуация

Боятся, и поэтому в их вежливости чувствуется неприязнь. Запятая перед И или поэтому?

Answer (score 2):

Боятся, **и поэтому** в их вежливости чувствуется неприязнь.

Сложносочиненное предложение, соединительный союз И, наречие "поэтому" определяет семантику отношений между двумя простыми предложениями как причинно-следственную.